# Разделить массив на две части

Tags: c++, алгоритм

Разделить массив на две части, поместив в первую элементы, больше среднего арифметического их суммы, а во вторую меньшие. 
Помогите, пожалуйста.

Comment: Чем Вам помочь?

Comment: @VladimirGamalian Помочь написать алгоритм, просто вообще вариантов нет как это сделать(

Comment: @t16bz "среднее арифметическое суммы" - это как так-то, а? "Сумма элементов" - это одно число. Среднее арифметическое кортежа из одного числа - само это число. Короче, составитель задания в математике разбирается не лучше своих ученичков.

Comment: Можно сначала вычислить среднее арифметическое, затем в новый массив сначала скопировать те элементы, которые больше получившегося числа, затем оставшиеся.

Comment: @VladimirGamalian не могу разобраться, как числа записать в новый массив, если не сложно, можно примерчик?

Comment: Вы используете `std::vector` или встроенные массивы?

Comment: @VladimirGamalian вот что я написал `for (int i = 0; i < size - 1; i++) {
  s += a[i];
 }

 s = s / size;
 printf("%d \n", s);

 for (int j = 0; j < size - 1; j++) {
  if (a[j] < s) {
  // ...
 }

 for (int k = 0; k < size - 1; k++) {
  printf("%d ", b[k]);
 }`

Comment: Я голосую за закрытие этого вопроса как не соответствующего теме, потому что SO - не фриланс-биржа.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если задача, получить новый массив, в котором сначала идут элементы больше среднего арифметического, затем остальные, то достаточно отсортировать массив по убыванию:

```
#include <algorithm>

int main() {
    int a[8] = { 32, 71, 12, 45, 26, 80, 53, 33 };
    std::sort(a, a + 8, std::greater<int>());
}
```

В результата в массиве `a` сначала будут идти элементы больше средне арифметического.

[Рабочий пример.](https://repl.it/Cx3E/0)

Comment: Извините, забыл написать что в задании сказано что части не сортировать. Мне кажется Ваш пример как раз под это подходит(

Comment: @t16bz тогда примерно так https://repl.it/Cx36/5

Comment: сложность O(n log(n)) там где нужно O(n)? =\

Comment: @yrHeTaTeJlb да, вы правы, излишняя сложность.

Answer (score 1):

Это как раз то, что делает алгоритм [`std::partition`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/partition/), или [`std::stable_partition`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/stable_partition/). Второй алгоритм сохраняет относительный порядок элементов. Использование выглядит так:

```
std::partition(&arr[0], &arr[size], std::bind1st(std::greater<int>(), mean));
```

или можно так, если ваш компилятор поддерживает С++11:

```
std::partition(&arr[0], &arr[size], std::bind(std::greater<int>(), mean, _1));
```

Весь код выглядит так:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <numeric>

int main()
{
    int arr[] = {32, 21, 34, 44, 17, 26, 7, 16};
    int size = sizeof(arr) / sizeof(int);
    int summ = std::accumulate(&arr[0], &arr[size], 0);
    int mean = summ / size;
    std::stable_partition(&arr[0], &arr[size], std::bind1st(std::less<int>(), mean));

    std::cout << mean << std::endl;
    for(int i = 0; i < size; ++i){
        std::cout << arr[i] << " ";
    }  
}
```

http://cpp.sh/5tyr

Comment: Красивое решение. Только вроде в начало здесь встанут элементы меньше среднего.

Comment: @VladimirGamalian, и правда, не внимательно прочитал задание. Заменил `std::greater` на `std::less`

Comment: Вроде там в комментариях автор просил чтобы части остались в том же порядке.

Comment: @VladimirGamalian, без проблем, заменил `std::partition` на `std::stable_partition`

Comment: Для отрицательных чисел может дать ошибку.

Comment: @VladimirGamalian, можно пример таких данных, на которых возникнет ошибка?

Comment: -2, -1, -4, -3 например, дает -1 -2 -4 -3

Comment: @VladimirGamalian, сумма -10, среднее -2.5. -2 и -1 больше -2.5, а -4 и -3 меньше -2.5. Все правильно

Comment: Порядок не соблюдается, должно быть -2, -1, -4, -3

Comment: @VladimirGamalian, тут дело не в отрицательных числах. Я использовал тип `int` для хранения суммы и среднего арифметического. Таким образом диапазон перестраивается относительно `2`. Получается -1 и -2 -4 -3. Если сделать [так](http://cpp.sh/6tc57) то получится -2, -1, -4, -3

Comment: С положительными округление получается в нужную сторону, и на них не проявляется такой эффект.